# How to start music at a specific second in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

I was looking at the API:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play

It says I can start the song at a certain position.  However, 1 of 2 things happen.  Either the song plays normally from the start or it plays really fuzzy-like.  I'm not sure why I can inconsistent results either.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("music/Glorious Morning 2.mp3")
#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(52.0)#this won't work either
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 52.0)
```

I'm not sure why it's not working.  Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to start music at a specific second?

Comment: Works fine for me with `Python 2.7.6` and `pygame 1.9.1`

Comment: I'll have to check what versions I have when I get home.  What OS are you using?  I have Windows 8

Comment: @starrify My Python version is `2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`.  I'm not sure how to check my Pygame version.

Comment: I just updated both Python and Pygame and it worked!  Thank you. You can post that as a solution and I'll check it off

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Well, it's quite glad to see your problem solved. What I provided is not an answer but just a hint, and it's you who solved the problem. You could post an answer yourself and accept it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Python version is `2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`. I'm not sure what Pygame version was, but I just updated both Python and Pygame and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet tested on both Windows 10 and Android. Note that the music file is a mp3 !

```
import pygame.mixer

#SOUND_FILE = 'c:/temp/JMJ.mp3'
SOUND_FILE = '/storage/emulated/0/music/JMJ.mp3'

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load(SOUND_FILE)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=1626) # 1626 seconds from beginning

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.wait()
```